# Undo changes of '2to3' library

Tags: python, bash, python-2to3, lib2to3

I had some python code in my SSH Project Folder which I had to convert from Python 2.7 to Python 3.*. Hence I installed the library 2to3.

However, before running the command `2to3 . -w`, I navigated to the ROOT directory which contained all the Python and Conda relevant library files by mistake and ran my code from there.

So I think that has changed all the python files from the root directory and not just my project-specific files. Hence I am getting multiple errors now while running the code.

By any chance, is there any way to undo these changes? I tried `conda update --all` to upgrade my packages but nothing is happening. Is re-installing everything the only way to fix this?

Comment: Possibly relevant package: [3to2](https://pypi.org/project/3to2/)

Comment: @Brian but that will convert all Python 3 relevant codes as well

Comment: Yes, reinstalling the libraries is probably the only reliable way to fix this.